# NUnit - how to dynamically run a subset of tests

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am using NUnit to drive Selenium WebDriver tests via the console runner.  Because these are WebDriver tests (and not standard unit tests), tests can fail for external reasons, such as a web page timing out.

I need to be able to RE-RUN any failed tests automatically to see if the test is failing because of a test violation, or just because the test failed due to a timeout.

I already log pass/fail status into a database, and what I want to do is automatically re-run any failed tests, immediately after the original test run.  I can do this manually of course, but that takes the fun out of automated testing!

How can I dynamically tell NUnit to run a group of tests in code?  (I know how to generate the list/array of failed tests, but don't know how to pass that list or array of tests to NUnit to re-run dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research on this earlier. There is a feature requested but won't be out until the `NUnit 3.0` is released. I also don't think you can dynamically execute any failed tests without writing custom attribute yourself at this moment. However, there is a project called [NUnit retry](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit-retry/) gives a little bit  of flexibility. The `Retry` attribute can help you out in case the `UI` tests failure because of external reason. It gives you the option to retry the test `n` number of time.

```
private static int run = 0;

...

[Test]
[Retry(Times = 3, RequiredPassCount = 2)]
public void One_Failure_On_Three_Should_Pass()
{
    run++;

    if (run == 1)
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }

    Assert.Pass();
}
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/slvnperron/NUnit-retry)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately I could not get NUnit-retry to work for me.  I get stuck on fetching via NuGet, the package would install, but without the dll.